# End kernel panic another syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-one, linux-headers

Ubuntu 19 update fail .
I have used terminal to update18.04 to 19 but after 91% download it fails not working and after restarting it is showing error. Even log in is not opening.

Comment: You should tell us how you upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 19.x?   Ubuntu by default only releases from LTS to next LTS, or every release (so 18.04 upgrades to 18.10, then 19.04 and not direct).  To jump from 18.04 LTS to 19.04 isn't possible unless you had problems with your sources, or forced it - in which case I'd suggest re-install because your system was in an unknown state anyway.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19;  Ubuntu release generally are *yy.mm* in format, with some exceptions, eg. Ubuntu Core 18 being last year's appliance ready IoT geared release (which are *yy* in format).  Standard server/desktop/.. releases have two per year so are *yy.mm*

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-19-04-disco-dingo

Comment: I have followed this but after downloading of 91% problem occured

Comment: That tells you how to upgrade 18.10 to 19.04 (not 18.04 to 19.04); I'd recommend sticking to Ubuntu tested methods such as found on the official release notes  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes   Check what you have done as that link does not match your question!

Comment: If you were on 18.04 LTS, then you would be doing an unsupported & untested upgrade, which I wouldn't trust.  I would re-install from a 19.04 ISO using 'something-else' & no format.  It notes your added programs, erases system directories, installs, then re-adds programs (if from Ubuntu repos) without touching user files. That method is tested by Ubuntu (unlike 18.04 to non-lts 19.04)

Comment: upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04 is possible with this method : https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-ubuntu-19-04-directly-from-command-line just FYI

Comment: @tatsu .. but it is not supported. It might work - or it might not. The only upgrade way that is supported is from LTS to LTS, or from one version to the next.

Comment: @SorenA yeah either way I recommend never upgrading to all non-experts. even recomended upgrade paths have a high tendency towards errors and bugs. and any noob can work the LiveCD USB installer and that method is sure fire.